# How to replace OutputProjectionWrapper in tensforflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have following code snippet for seq2seq decoder with attention mechanism. It works in tensorflow 1.13. Now I need to upgrade to tensorflow 2.0 with keras but the tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper was removed in tensorflow 2.0 already. How to implement it?

```
attention_mechanism = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BahdanauAttention(
                num_units, memory=memory,
         memory_sequence_length=self.encoder_inputs_actual_length)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units)
attn_cell = tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper(
                cell, attention_mechanism, attention_layer_size)
out_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(
                attn_cell, self.output_size, reuse=reuse)
decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(
                cell=out_cell, helper=helper,
                initial_state=out_cell.zero_state(
                    dtype=tf.float32, batch_size=self.batch_size))
final_outputs, _, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(
                decoder=decoder, output_time_major=True,
                impute_finished=True, 
maximum_iterations=self.input_steps
            )
```

I read the https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/neural-networks-and/9781492037354/ch04.html but didn't work out how to add that full connection to my case.

I tried to use the latest seq2seq addons with eager mode as following, there is no syntax error but I'm not sure if it is correct. The previous tf 1.13 version prediction accuracy achieves 90% quickly but the new tf2.0 version accuracy is around 60% always.

```
attention_mechanism = tfa.seq2seq.BahdanauAttention(num_units,memory,memory_sequence_length)
lstm_cell = layers.LSTMCell(num_units)
attn_cell = tfa.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper(lstm_cell,attention_mechanism, attention_layer_size=num_units) 
output_layer = layers.Dense(self.output_size)
basic_decoder = tfa.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(cell=attn_cell, sampler=sampler,output_layer=output_layer,output_time_major=True,impute_finished=True,maximum_iterations=self.input_steps)
initial_state = attn_cell.get_initial_state(batch_size=self.batch_size,dtype=tf.float32).clone(cell_state=encoder_final_state)
final_outputs, _, _ = basic_decoder(encoder_outputs_sequence,initial_state=initial_state)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the reason the accuracy keeps around 60% is that the AttentionWrapper will output attention score by default, but in my case I need the actual output which will be used to calculate the next attention score. The solution is to set output_attention=False in AttentionWrapper:

```
attn_cell = tfa.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper(lstm_cell,attention_mechanism, 
attention_layer_size=num_units, output_attention=False)
```

Updated it here in case anyone meet the same question.